# Escape variables in tfs

Tags: tfs, deployment

I am using TFS to maintain some project. I am using two agents in pool. I need to configure to different variables for both, I set variables as:

```
var1_1 = 5
var2 = 1
```

and I want to use code something like:

```
echo $(var1_$(var2))
```

to escape it to 5 
instead I receive echo $(var1_1)

Is there any nice way to escape things like this?

Comment: Variables don't expand like that. What is the problem you are trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: I have two agents in pool and I have different passwords to database in both. I am using some gradle tasks with parameters to set proper passwords in application config. I need to pass two different variables to gradle task depending on agent it is working at. I do not want to duplicate commands.

Comment: Hi, I must have had changed approach cause I did not notice many dependencies and I did not have chance to check it :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define a variable in the Variables screen and use other variables as value, they will **be expanded automatically** (the build agent version should be new version 2.x).

I just created a simple test in powershell, it works properly. Variables could expand automatically.

[image]

The test powershell script:

```
# You can write your powershell scripts inline here. 
# You can also pass predefined and custom variables to this scripts using arguments

 Write-Host "Hello World"

echo $(var1_1)

echo $(var2)

echo $(var1_$(var2))

echo $(x)
```

The build result shows the variable expand properly:

[image]

You could also try to use  some 3rd-party extension such as [Variable Toolbox](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jessehouwing.jessehouwing-vsts-variable-tasks) to help you manage build variable.